# PDO Query Showing No Results

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So previously my queries were working fine. I usually use mysql but have recently changed to a pre-configured vps through godaddy. Last night I was trying to connect to my server via PDO, which is showing the connection is being made.

Next I was trying to select the data from a table using:

```
global $conn;
$sql = "SELECT name FROM suppliers";
$stm = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute();
return $stm->fetch();
```

All this shows on my website is Connection Successful, Array

It doesn't show any array information or anything, just the word "Array". The table has information in it, so it should be displaying the results. Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: you're trying to print an array, which gives you the literal word `Array`. so... don't do that. print_r, var_dump, foreach, etc...

Comment: Additionally, how are you using this? I think you will only have the first row with this approach. I'd use `fetchAll` or put the `fetch` in a `while` then build an array with all data needed.

Comment: @chris85 Yes, you are correct. Thank you. Put it in a while statement and it worked.

Comment: @BlakeConnally Answer resolves the issue or it was different?

Comment: @chris85 yes it did resolve the issue, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get `Array` because you are echoing an array. `Fetch` returns an array,

> PDO::FETCH_BOTH (default): returns an array indexed by both column name and 0-indexed column number as returned in your result set

Since you are querying a full table you probably want all the results so you should loop the `fetch` and return that array.

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM suppliers";
$stm = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute();
while($row = $stm->fetch()) {
    $returned_array[] = $row['name'];
}
return $returned_array;
```

Then iterate over this where ever you are using it for all the supplier names.

```
foreach(function_call_for_names() as $name) {
     echo $name;
}
```

Alternately, you could use the PDO [`fetchAll`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) function,

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM suppliers";
$stm = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute();
return $stm->fetchAll();
```

then

```
foreach(function_call_for_names() as $row) {
         echo $row['name'];
}
```